# Form where do i get elastic search version 5.5.2 with documentation?

Tags: elasticsearch

Official site of the Elastic Search has the latest version.
I couldn't find that version on the official site.

Comment: There's a version selector in the documentation, here you go: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/index.html and for downloading you have the past releases page: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases

Comment: @Val  many thanks ....